# Excelsior jet output (bat file) does not work in another systems

Tags: java

I want to create exe file from my java application for running without the need to installing `JRE` using `Excelsior JET`. bat file made, works properly in my computer but it does not work in another system. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the JET runtime with your you exe (rt folder), the easiest way is to package your application using the JET PACK application. Also you can use the Excelsior maven [plugin](https://www.excelsiorjet.com/maven-plugin).